# what is the use of universal unique identifier ,why its so much important in deployment?

Tags: services, deployment, features

What is the use of universal unique identifier in drupal7, why its play important role in deploy and service

Answer (score 3):

UUID is used to identify the same objects (like nodes, taxonomy_terms and users) across environments.

All of these has an ID, for nodes it's the `nid` (node id), but that is not reliable to use across environments, since it's serial (1, 2, 3 ...). Fx the about page on content staging environment might have id 5 while it on the production environment might have id 1.

Deploy is all about pushing content between environments, so if you make a change on your content staging site, you want to be able to push those changes to the correct node. Since nids can't be used, as they aren't *universially unique*, but only unique for the specific environment, we need something that is. That is exactly what uuids and the uuid module provide.

Comment: thanks for your awesome explanation , now i have one more doubt if on staging content site nid-13 haveing 123-4566-789 uuid so on after deploying content my nid will get change but uuid will remain constant ??

Comment: @Harshil The UUID will never change, so if you push a node from staging to production, the UUID will be the same (but the nid might not be) which makes it possible to push updates as well (since the UUID is the same, the system knows which node to update).